# Pinvoke issues with GCC compiled c++ dll in VB.net 2010

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

OK, I have tried to figure this out on my own. here is the issue I am having:

In order for the function to work in the dll, I have to send a pointer for a structure in my vb code, because I need the structure filled with data from the file, and vice versa. It was easier to compile the functions as a dll, then try to rewrite native C functions in vb, that I have never used like memmove().

Dll File works, as I also wrote a c++ app that called the functions from the dll, filled the structure in memory from the pointer, and then displays the data in the command prompt. I just need to figure out what is wrong with the visual basic side of things.

c++ header info for exported functions

```
#define MAX_CHEATS 150
struct SCheat
{
uint32_t address;
uint8_t byte1;
uint8_t saved_byte;
bool enabled;
bool saved;
char    name[22];
};
struct SCheatData
{
struct SCheat c[MAX_CHEATS];
uint32_t num_cheats;
};
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl S9xLoadCheatFile (const char *, struct SCheatData *Cheat);
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl S9xSaveCheatFile (const char *, struct ScheatData *Cheat);
```

I wrote a c++ app to test dll functionality, and it works perfect.

I should also mention the original versions of the c++ code was found on github. I only needed the functions to load/save cht files for Snes9x. If I can figure this out, I can easily add the rest of the emulators cheat file structures, and loading/saving functions, and my app will generate the cht files for any emulator, while saving all cheats in a central database.

So now we get down to the vb part.

Here are the structures and calls I have defined in my app.

```
<StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure SCheat
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public address As UInteger
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public byte1 As Byte
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public saved_byte As Byte
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public enabled As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public saved As Integer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=22)> Public name() As Char
End Structure
<StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure SCheatData
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=150)> Public Shared c() As SCheat = Arrays.InitializeWithDefaultInstances(Of SCheat)(150)
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> Public num_cheats As UInteger
End Structure
```

and here is how I defined the functions.

```
<DllImport("c:\minGW\bin\Cheat_Functions.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Function _Z16S9xLoadCheatFilePKcP10SCheatData(ByVal filename As String, ByVal cheat As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Declare Function S9xLoadCheatFile Lib "c:\minGW\bin\Cheat_Functions.dll" Alias "_Z16S9xLoadCheatFilePKcP10SCheatData" (ByVal filename As String, ByRef cheat As IntPtr) As Integer


Declare Function S9xSaveCheatFile Lib "c:\minGW\bin\Cheat_Functions.dll" Alias "_Z16S9xSaveCheatFilePKcP10SCheatData" (ByVal filename As String, ByRef cheat As SCheatData) As Integer
```

I have tried passing the structure by ref, and it crashed with a non descriptive message about reading/writing protected memory. I tried marshaling a variable of the structuretoptr, and it gets a little farther, but corrupts all the memory in the app. I think it is a matter of not completely understanding how pinvoke and marshalling actually work, or maybe my structure doesnt match what the dll is looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: sorry but I forgot you were targeting VB, you shouldn't have much problem to translate my code to it though :D**

The following works for me :

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var intPtr = GetData();
            var ptrToStructure = Marshal.PtrToStructure<SCheatData>(intPtr);
        }

        [DllImport("mydll.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetData();

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct SCheat
        {
            public uint address;
            public byte byte1;
            public byte saved_byte;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] public bool enabled;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)] public bool saved;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 22)] public string name;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SCheatData
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 150, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct)] public SCheat[]
                c;

            public uint num_cheats;
        }
    }
}
```

And :

```
// mydll.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
typedef unsigned char      uint8_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint32_t;
#define MAX_CHEATS 150

struct SCheat
{
    uint32_t address;
    uint8_t byte1;
    uint8_t saved_byte;
    bool enabled;
    bool saved;
    char    name[22];
};

struct SCheatData
{
    struct SCheat c[MAX_CHEATS];
    uint32_t num_cheats;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) SCheatData* GetData()
{
    SCheatData* data = new SCheatData();
    data->num_cheats = MAX_CHEATS;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < MAX_CHEATS; i++)
    {
        SCheat c;
        c.address = 1234;
        c.byte1 = 0xAB;
        c.saved_byte = 0xCD;
        c.enabled = true;
        c.saved = true;
        strcpy(c.name, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstu");
        data->c[i] = c;
    }
    return data;
}
```

I have used [PInvoke Interop Assistant](https://clrinterop.codeplex.com/) which is quite helpful for generating signatures, also be careful about the different overloads of `Marshal.PtrToStructure` as not all flavors will work for any case.

Comment: So, if I am understanding what I am looking at here, you are creating the pointer in C++, and using a function in the dll to send the pointer addresss back to c#/vb.net to use the structure that is in unprotected memory at the pointer address. Correct me if I am wrong, as C/C++ are not my everyday programming languages. I am using it because it seemed easier then rewriting native c functions like memmove(), which have no like function in vb .net. I will play with what is there, and see what I get. Thank you for the direction to go in. I have been fighting with this for a couple of days.

Comment: Correct, there are no miracles in this regard -> you need a managed representation of a struct anyway since for obvious reason a native one won't be visible to .NET. And there comes back the usual workflow of C++ for deleting allocated types and so on. The Marshal class does these conversions between both worlds but you just have to read twice as some methods have subtle differences as I've laid out earlier. You can also use C++/CLI to facilitate the process, have your code in a classic static library then reference it there and present your native types to .NET.

Comment: So that kind of worked. :) I am getting some where. no more annoying memory corruption errors. Now I have to figure out why the values in the structure are wrong.

Comment: if I leave SCheatData* data = new SCheatData(); that way, i get issues from gcc like undefined reference to 'operator new(unsigned int)' if I change it to SCheatData* data; then it compiles, when I fill the structure the pointer points at, I get wrong values back in vb. eg num_cheats == 5000+, when it should never go past 150. I will mess with it a little more, but I think i am on the right track here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Thank you for the help, it didnt quite do it, but the direction was the answer I needed. :)

Code Fixes.

C++ Header:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl S9xLoadCheatFile (const char *);
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl S9xSaveCheatFile (const char *);

__declspec(dllexport) SCheatData* __cdecl GetData();
struct SCheatData data1;
```

Dll.cpp:

```
SCheatData* __cdecl GetData()
{
   return &data1;
}
```

interact with struct data1 directly in save and load functions.

VB Code.

```
<StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Public Structure SCheat
Public address As UInteger
Public byte1 As Byte
Public saved_byte As Byte
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)> Public enabled As Boolean
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)> Public saved As Boolean
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=22, ArraySubType:=UnmanagedType.Struct)> Public name() As Char
End Structure
<StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Public Structure SCheatData
<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=150)> Public c() As SCheat
Public num_cheats As UInteger
End Structure

<DllImport("c:\minGW\bin\Cheat_Functions.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Function _Z16S9xLoadCheatFilePKc(ByVal filename As String) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("c:\minGW\bin\Cheat_Functions.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Function _Z7GetDatav() As IntPtr
End Function

Private sub try()
  Dim tryv As String = "C:\\Users\\Diane\\Desktop\\snes9x\\Cheats\\Super Mario World (U) [!].cht"
  Dim anotherP As New SCheatData
  MsgBox(_Z16S9xLoadCheatFilePKc(tryv))
  anotherP = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(_Z7GetDatav(), GetType(SCheatData))
  MsgBox(anotherP.num_cheats)
end sub
```

This works for loading, which verifys the structure is correct. I am thinking that this should work for the save function as well. At least I know that if I do have an issue with it, that the problem will not be with the structures. :) Will post back if I have issues with using this for save feature.

Edit, Just tested reversing with System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(anotherP, _Z7GetDatav, True), and it worked. So I guess what I was was a couple of things defining the structures properly, and that structuretoptr requires a pointer made in the dll. If only I knew these things 3 days ago. Thank you for your help, even though I still had to mess with it a bit for it to work for my purposes, it gave me a new direction to look in, which was actually helpful.

Now, I just have to do the same thing for all the other emulators. lol. :) Shouldnt take to long now that I sort of get it.

Comment: Ran into a slight issue, I cant seem to set values in .C() if I define a variable as SCheatData. Any ideas Keeps giving me Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. Dont know what this means exactly.